# Are there any advantages of a cascaded FIR vs direct form FIR?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response

I've been reading up on a few different realizations of FIR filters and recently came across the concept of a cascaded FIR filter. That is, an FIR filter of higher order, represented by a cascade of second order direct form FIR filters.

What are the advantages of using a cascaded FIR filter over a direct form FIR filter? Does it help reduce quantization errors?

I'm also somewhat familiar with IIR filters being implemented as cascaded second order filters. Are there similarities between this and a cascaded FIR filter?